# Как удалить библиотеку через pip?

Tags: python, pip

Как удалить библиотеку через pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так

```sh
py -m pip uninstall <name-package>
```

Можно удалить все библиотеки, собранные в файл, например `requirements.txt`

```sh
py -m pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

[Документация](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/)